# Why X-ray emission is able to exit the volume without essential photo-absorption

Tags: radiation, x-rays

My question is written in the title

I am currently studying of radiation of plasma

And I can't get it why it works like this.

"Why X-ray can penetrate the volume without photo-absorption."

Comment: Not sure it'd matter, but what sources are you considering for the X-ray emissions?

Answer (score 1):

There is always some absorption. But maybe the point is that the x-ray emission lines of an element are lower in energy than the corresponding x-ray absorption threshold energies.

For example, the Cu K$\alpha$ and K$\beta$ x-ray emission lines are below the Cu K absorption edge. At energies just above the Cu $1s$ binding energy, the attenuation in copper is about five times stronger.